# Call start startActivityForResult inside class

Tags: java, android

I need to call `startActivityForResult` from inside class, but I am getting no     `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

File: SignUpFragment.java

```
public class SignUpFragment extends Fragment {

    ImageView imageView;


    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public SignUpFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor

        Test test = new Test();
        test.getImageData();

    }
}
```

P.S: `Test.java` is not an `Activity`, its class and I extends `Activity` to get access to `startActivityForResult`

file Test.java

```
public class Test extends Activity {

    public void getImageData() {
        Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        pickIntent.setType("image/*");

        startActivityForResult(pickIntent, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Log.d(“Reps”, ”Called”);
    }

}
```

Update: here is the error log :

```
mozeh E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.example.moaaznash.userregistrationmozeh, PID: 28091
     java.lang.NullPointerException
         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
         at com.example.moaaznash.mozehlibraryandroid.TestMozeh1.startPhotoLibs(TestMozeh1.java:52)
         at com.example.moaaznash.userregistrationmozeh.SignUpFragment$1.onClick(SignUpFragment.java:101)
         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

     [ 03-19 10:08:41.231  1615: 1809 D/         ]
     HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb990e140, tid 1809
```

Comment: can you add your log ? or what cased this null ?\

Comment: nmozeh E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                             Process: com.example.moaaznash.userregistrationmozeh, PID: 22753
                                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Why are you extending it to Activity. Activity is building block of the user interface. You don't seem to have UI in that activity and please post you complete log in code section and not in comment section.

Comment: I Extended because i need access to startActivityForResult from inside the same class, I don`t want to pass the activity to the method, if i pass the activity to the method then i have to define onActivityResult in the fragment not inside the class

Comment: Normally you are not allowed to create an Activity instance explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test extends Activity {

    public void getImageData() {
        Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        pickIntent.setType("image/*");
        if (pickIntent == 1) {
            startActivity(pickIntent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(“Reps”,”Called”);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MOAAZNAHSAWI in which value does your result reside and what value are you expecting in result to run activity?

Comment: dont matter the value i just need to be Called

Comment: There is no condition to satisfy?

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to put the getImageData() and the onActivityResult to the Activity class containing the Fragment (and communicate between the Activity and Fragment through listeners for instance).

But below is an alternative

```
public class SignUpFragment extends Fragment {
    private final int PICK_ID = 1;

    public SignUpFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static SignUpFragment newInstance() {
        SignUpFragment fragment = new SignUpFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getImageData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_ID && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("TAG", "onActivityResult");

            if (data != null) {
                try {
                    InputStream inputStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                    //...
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void getImageData(){
        Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        pickIntent.setType("image/*");

        startActivityForResult(pickIntent, PICK_ID);
    }
}
```

And in your activity simply put something like this

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                     .beginTransaction()
                     .add(android.R.id.content, SignUpFragment.newInstance())
                     .commit();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are treating Activity like a ordinary Java class, and not like another Activity. Due to this, when you call startActivityForResult() you get a nullpointerexception as the Activity's onCreate() has not been called, which means that its current instance is not valid for calling startActivityForResult().